# How to add a checkbox inside Table for Reportlab in python?

Tags: python, reportlab

I am trying to generate PDF through python by using reportlab. (beginner level)

Basically, I want to create a table with a checkbox inside.

For example, refer to below code:

```
    ...
    data =[
        [Paragraph("Option 1",style=custom_para), "anything"],
        [Paragraph("Option 2",style=custom_para), "anything"]
    ]

    t=Table(data, style=style_table, colWidths=[100, 100])
    Story.append(t)
    ...
```

I already tested that the above code can generate table correctly.

Now, I want something further, which is something like:

```
    ...
    data =[
        [Paragraph("Option 1",style=custom_para), checkbox_1],
        [Paragraph("Option 2",style=custom_para), checkbox_2]
    ]

    t=Table(data, style=style_table, colWidths=[100, 100])
    Story.append(t)
    ...
```

How should I implement the checkbox_1, checkbox_2?

What is the most efficient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

I hope this helps. I created checkbox_1 and checkbox_2 as instances of the class:

```
class InteractiveCheckBox(Flowable):
    def __init__(self, text='A Box'):
        Flowable.__init__(self)
        self.text = text
        self.boxsize = 12

    def draw(self):
        self.canv.saveState()
        form = self.canv.acroForm
        form.checkbox(checked=False,
                      buttonStyle='check',
                      name=self.text,
                      tooltip=self.text,
                      relative=True,
                      size=self.boxsize)
        self.canv.restoreState()
        return
```

Then you can do something like:

```
...
checkbox_1 = InteractiveCheckBox('cb1')
checkbox_2 = InteractiveCheckBox('cb2')
data =[
    [Paragraph("Option 1",style=custom_para), checkbox_1],
    [Paragraph("Option 2",style=custom_para), checkbox_2]
]

t=Table(data, style=style_table, colWidths=100])
Story.append(t)
...
```

Answer (score 5):

I could not find a perfect solution. In the end, I achieved similar result by drawing a rectangle inside the table. And the rectangle is implemented with below code:

```
class flowable_rect(Flowable):
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        Flowable.__init__(self)
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def draw(self):
        self.canv.rect(0, 0, self.width, self.height, fill=0)
```

Thus, it can be called directly such as:

```
rect = flowable_rect(6, 6)
t_opt_1=Table([[rect,option_1]], style=style_table, 
             colWidths=[100, 200], hAlign="LEFT")
```